# How do I add a file to the build root filesystem?

Tags: bitbake

I need to include a file when I build a package, but the file itself is not required at all at runtime.

I have been told to look at how to do it using a `do_` function, but have been unable to find a suitable function in any documentation. I would assume this could be done trivially, but simply specifying which file to add.

Again, I'm not looking for a way to add the files to the final image. This is just for building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full documentation about [tasks](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/tasks.html). They all start with `do_`, so you were advised to extend one of them. Also (as written in docs) packages may have additional tasks, that come from classes - files `.bbclass`, that are applied to your package's recipe with `inherit` keyword. To get full list of exactly your package tasks use command

```
bitbake -c listtasks <your package name>
```

Actually this way you just call task `do_listtasks` of your package, `do_listtasks` is also... a task)

So.. first you need to understand to what task you need to append your file. Tasks have pretty straightforward names, so to use your file during compilation, you need task `do_compile`, and so on.

Now, it is not clear, how you are going to actually add your file to the build, but looks like also somehow by recipe of your package. That means you should place your file in folder `files` (there are options about this folder naming) next by your recipe, than add file to variable `SRC_URI` like this:

```
SRC_URI = " \
.....
file://your-file-in-folder-files.ext \
.....
"
```

By doing this, you tell bitbake to append this file to [WORKDIR](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-WORKDIR) during `do_unpack` task. More on this [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#writing-a-new-recipe), especially in [3.3.5](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html?highlight=file://#fetching-code).

Now to actually your question)) Suppose you need to use your file during `do_compile` task, but *before* the actual compilation actions. Than in your recipe **extend do_compile like this**:

```
do_compile_prepend() {
  cp ${WORKDIR}/your-file-in-folder-files.ext ${S}/some/subpath/inside/sources
}
```

Similarly to do something with your file **after** some actual task actions, create function with `_append` suffix. For example, `do_configure_append` or `do_compile_append`.

Here [WORKDIR](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-WORKDIR) is some folder under Yocto `build` directory, where all your package stuff, needed for build your package, is placed, [S](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-S) is a special folder with downloaded and unpacked source code under `WORKDIR` and `do_compile_prepend` (and others) is just a bash-script.

Also consider folder [D](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-D) (it is also locates under `WORKDIR`). It contains files, that actually shall go into resulting image during image creating. So if somehow your file finds the way to the resulting image, remove it directly from `D` like this:

```
do_install_append() {
  rm -f ${D}/path/to/your/file/in/resulting/rootfs/your-file-in-folder-files.ext
}
```

Well... this is more overview, than a exact answer, but hope this helps!